# Visual Studio Publish & Deploy Issues - Using old assemblies no matter what

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish, web-deployment

I've published and deployed a website. It originally had a hard-coded path which I've now removed. I've cleaned, deleted, updated, and banged my head on the wall, but the deployed code is still referencing the hard coded path.

See here:

http://www.iso15926.net

I've checked the whole solution to ensure the path doesn't exist. It works on my local machine when I run it, just not on the server.

I've checked the error on different machines to ensure it wasn't a browser cache issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you delete the `Temporary ASP.NET files`? On a 64 system, it's a path like this: `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`.

Comment: I didn't know about that folder so that's useful information - thanks. The folder was empty although I did restart the machine. It turns out there was an issue with my code not resolving a relative path correctly, but that doesn't explain why the error was referencing a hard-coded path from my original code. A phantom!